# Jenkinsapi with py2exe in python

Tags: python, py2exe

I blocked since some hours and i do not know how can i work around.
-I made a python script using jenkinsapi, this is working correctly.
-I´m trying to make a .exe file with py2exe, so I added jenkinsapi in the "includes" as I do usually, it compile correctly.
But when I run the .exe file, I got this error :

import jenkinsapi
  File "jenkinsapi__init__.pyc", line 69, in 
KeyError: 'jenkinsapi'

Impossible to find the problem, it seems that py2exe didn´t created the .pyd file of jenkinsapi.

Do someone had the same issue and can help me